# Batch para ENCONTRAR una carpeta y borrar su contenido

Tags: batch, msdos

tengo 50 computadores que semanalmente se tienen que **eliminar** los archivos de las carpetas de **DESCARGA, DOCUMENTOS y ESCRITORIO**. En algunos equipos estas carpetas estan en la partición D:, otros en la carpeta Usuario de la unidad C:. La idea es dejar un archivo batch en el Escritorio de cada computador y que éste pueda *encontrar* las carpetas mencionadas y eliminar los contenidos de ellas.

Conozco las instrucciones batch para cambiarme de carpeta y borrar su contenido, pero no sé (por más que lo busco por internet) como **"ENCONTRAR"** una carpeta para **saber su ruta** y así poder borrar su contenido. Sabiendo el procedimiento para una, podré replicarla para las otras.

Agradeceré mucho vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre tener un `batch` en la raíz de cada unidad (*si es que tienes varias*).

Puedes acceder a los directorios de los usuarios usando el siguiente comando por cada carpeta:

```
cd %userprofile%\Desktop
cd %userprofile%\Documents
cd %userprofile%\Dowloads
```

Con esto en mente puedes borrar todos los archivos con `del /s /q %userprofile%\Desktop *.*` y todas las carpetas con `rmdir /s /q %userprofile%\Desktop`

Otra opción más dinámica es realizar una búsqueda por nombre de carpeta. El archivo `batch` contendrá el siguiente script que busca por nombre de carpeta y elimina todos los archivos que contenga la carpeta principal.

**Para hacer las pruebas asegúrate de eliminar temporalmente la línea** `del /q "%%~dpa\*"` la cual se encarga de eliminar los archivos. También debes tener cuidado porque algunos programas crean carpetas al instalarse dentro de las que pretendes vaciar y es posible que dejen de funcionar al eliminar los archivos.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "carpeta=Desktop"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "%carpeta%"') do (
    echo %%~dpa
    del /q "%%~dpa\*"
)

PAUSE

endlocal
```

**Haz pruebas con archivos y carpetas que estés seguro que puedas eliminar. La responsabilidad de los efectos secundarios que tenga esta solución es completamente tuya.**

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Lo probé con carpeta "Temporal" que tenía archivos varios y ningún problema. Ahora lo adaptaré a las tres carpetas que necesito y muchas gracias por el tiempo que le dedicaste a mi problema. Aprendí mucho de esto.